# How to expand contents of one table by contents of another table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have 2 tables:

1. Calendar table

```
Date
----
01/01/2022
02/01/2022
03/01/2022
.
.
.
```

2. Resource table

```
Resource Name
-------------
Resource A
Resource B
.
.
.
```

I want to combine both tables into one table with the following format:

```
Resource Name | Date
---------------------
Resource A    | 01/01/2022
Resource A    | 02/01/2022
Resource A    | 03/01/2022
Resource A    |     .
Resource A    |     .
Resource A    |     .
Resource B    | 01/01/2022
Resource B    | 02/01/2022
Resource B    | 03/01/2022
Resource B    |     .
Resource B    |     .
Resource B    |     .
.
.
.
```

How can this be done using either Power Query or DAX [PowerBi]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In powerquery,add column, custom column

= NameOfOtherTableGoesHere

Then click the arrow atop the column and expand to rows

[image]